# File input has stopped app in apache cordova

Tags: android, html, file, cordova, input

I was using an angular plugin to crop images after selected with an input file. In the browser works fine, but after build my app in Android, When I click the input file, It lets me choose the file, but after choosing it, the app has stopped with the typical message in a modal.

Then I use a simple  to see if there was a problem with the plugin, but the issue became again.
I don't want to use a cordova plugin to choose files. I want the simple html input file.

Can somebody help me with this?
Thanks!

---

I've solved using the https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera
There is an option to select the source media from the gallery and also you can specify if it is a picture. 
Works fine for me!

Comment: When you debug with Chrome Remote Debug, what do you see?

Comment: Sorry, but how can i debug with chrome remotly?
I chrome works fine, not in the app. Thanks

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging